# JPA and searching by several dates

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, jpql

This is my entity class

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity(name = "words")
public class Word {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Group group;

    @ManyToOne
    private User user;

    @NotBlank
    private String englishWord;

    @NotBlank
    private String russianWord;

    private LocalDate created = LocalDate.now();

    private final LocalDate plusOneDay = created.plusDays(1);

    private final LocalDate plusTwoDays = created.plusDays(2);

    private final LocalDate plusFiveDays = created.plusDays(5);

    private final LocalDate plusTenDays = created.plusDays(10);

    private final LocalDate plusTwoWeeks = created.plusWeeks(2);

    private final LocalDate plusSixWeeks = created.plusWeeks(6);

    private final LocalDate plusThreeMonths = created.plusMonths(3);

    private final LocalDate plusSixMonths = created.plusMonths(6);

    private final LocalDate plusOneYear = created.plusYears(1);
}
```

As you see I have several `LocalDate` fields.

I need to check, is `created`, **OR** `plusOneDay`, **OR** `plusTwoWeek`, `etc` matches with today's day. If it matches - it must be got from a database. I can write something like that:

```
Set<Word> findAllByCreatedOrByPlusOneDayOrByPlusTwoDays(LocalDate date);
```

But the request will be too long, and it doesn't work.
Is there another way to check several fields by one date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you may use Specification. Doc: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.7.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#specifications

I made some code, that may help.

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification;

import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Root;
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class WordSpecs {

        public static Specification<Word> isOneDateEqual(final LocalDate date){
            return new Specification<Word>() {
                @Override
                public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Word> root, CriteriaQuery<?> criteriaQuery, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
                    final Predicate created = criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("created"), date);
                    final Predicate plusOneDay = criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("plusOneDay"), date);
                    return criteriaBuilder.or(created, plusOneDay);
                }
            };

        }
    }
```

Repository Class:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaSpecificationExecutor;

@org.springframework.stereotype.Repository
public interface WordRepository extends JpaRepository<Word, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor {


}
```

Service class

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.List;

@Service
public class WordService {

    @Autowired
    private WordRepository repository;

    public List<Word> findMatched(final LocalDate date){
        return repository.findAll(WordSpecs.isOneDateEqual(date));

    }

}
```

Edit:

Much easier, you may like:

```
@Query("SELECT word FROM Word word WHERE 1 = 1 AND word.user.userId = :userId AND ( word.created = :date OR word.plus1 = :date ) " )
List<Word> findMatched(@Param("date") final LocalDate date, @Param("userId") final Long userId);
```

Comment: What about checking the id of a User?

Comment: Why do you need to check the id of user? I did not undestand.

Comment: Because each word is mapped by a User, you can see a special field in my code

Comment: I got it. You can just add a AND word.user.user_id = :userId. Something like this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can pass a list of possible dates:

```
Set<Word> findAllByCreatedIn(List<LocalDate> dates);
```

and then invoke it as:

```
repo.findAllByCreatedIn(List.of(date, date.minusDays(1), date.minusDays(2)));
```

Comment: I must check other date fields too, not only created

Comment: @MaksimRybalkin but they are computed from `created` field, right? That's why I passed  `date.minusDays(1)` and `date.minusDays(2)` into the list.

Comment: Each of those dates can be today's one.
I need to check, is created, OR plusOneDay, OR plusTwoWeek, etc matches with today's day. If it matches - it must be got from database

Comment: @MaksimRybalkin so you need to check if `created == date` or `created.plusDays(1) == date` or `created.plusDays(2) == date`, so in other words if `created == date` or `created == date.minusDays(1)` or `created == date` or `created == date.minusDays(2)`.